# Hotkey to open files in Windows 10 File Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, hotkeys

Is there a hotkey to open files in Windows 10 File Explorer?

For example, I have multiple image files I want to open in Photos. Is there a faster way to open them quickly than selecting all of them, right click, open? Could I instead select them all and press a hotkey to open them? I open a lot of images it would really improve the speed to going through them if I could use a hotkey.

Comment: Hitting "Enter" isn't working?

Comment: If you now select them, right click and press `Open`, you can also just press `Enter`. (waaa, just too late :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigating to the folder and then pressing CTRL + A (select all), and then hitting enter will open all picture files.